# Display the intent of Email by Scheduled

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, alarmmanager

In my application I want to send email by scheduled time. The email must send through intent, and this intent should raise if the application is closed by the scheduled time.

How can i done this? What's the best way to do this?

Anyone know this means, guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've simply did this by code:

```
Intent startupIntent = new Intent(con, ServiceActivity.class);
startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
con.startActivity(startupIntent);
```